# Create a fullscreen xaml dialog that dims the background and makes it modal

Tags: xaml, popup, fullscreen

I am working on a Windows 10 Xaml app.  I need to show a modal dialog on the screen that dims everything on the background.  Popup's are not modal, so my plan is to create a fullscreen popup, that has a transparent background (I will control the dim with opacity) and then have my dialog in the middle of the screen).  Before I go down this route, can anyone recommend a better idea to achieve this affect?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [ContentDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog.aspx) to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Thanks - this gives me a modal dialog, which solves part of my problem.  But how can I make the background dimmer when it's visible?

Comment: @George It does it automatically. See [examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=contentdialog+uwp+xaml&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjklYO6u9zLAhWnvoMKHerKCZ8Q_AUIBygB&biw=1920&bih=943)